# arbitrary unpackable functor class in python

Tags: python, class, tuples, functor, magic-methods

Is there a way to implement a class so that it can be mapped over with the map-function and unpacked like a tuple?
Something like that:

```
class T
...
t = T(1,[1,2,3])
a, b = t
a==1 #True
b==[1,2,3] #True
list(map(str,t))==['1','2','3'] #True
```

I tried using `__iter__` but it turns out to be used for unpacking and map.

I basically want to decide what part of the tuple I map over and return and unpack just like a normal tuple.

Comment: `list(map(str,t)) == ['1','2','2'] ` should be `list(map(str,t)) == ['1', '[1,2,3]']` **?**

Comment: Are you trying to make unpacking and `map` treat your object as if it has different elements? Not possible, unless you want to do some serious black magic with the call stack.

Comment: Basically yes... I tried __getitem__ to unpack in a different way but it comes down to __iter__

Comment: How are you getting `'1', '2', '2'`?

Comment: I want to treat the class like a list when mapping and like a tuple when unpacking.

Comment: @codemonkey: That still doesn't explain the behavior you showed.  If what user2357112 suggested is right, you want to treat it like a list in one situation and like a list *with different contents* in another situation (i.e., as if it were `(1, [1, 2, 3])` and later as if it were just `[1, 2, 3]`).  As he said, that is not possible.  Both map and unpacking do the same thing, which is iteration.

Comment: @BrenBarn Well I was trying to do something that works in Haskell where you can implement an interface to make your datatype a functor/mapable and extract values with pattern matching aka unpacking...

Answer (score 1):

Use the enumeration in a class **iter** and check type value:

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.data = args

    def __iter__(self):
        for value in self.data:
            if type(value) is str or type(value) is int:
                yield str(value)
            elif type(value) is list:
                for x in value:
                    yield str(x)

t = list(T(1, [1, 2]))

print t
```

Comment: This gives me: list(map(str,t)) == ['1', '[1, 2]']
not ['1','2','3']